# Plotting behavior in console vs script

Tags: python, spyder

I am new to Python, and I am confused by the follwing behavior. When I execute this script, it does not plot anything.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

q_arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
a1 = np.c_[q_arr[:,0],q_arr[:,1]]

x = np.random.rand(3)
y = np.random.rand(3)

x = np.reshape(x,(3,1))
y = np.reshape(y,(3,1))

a2 = np.concatenate((x,y),1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(a2[:,0],a2[:,1],45,'blue')
plt.show()
```

However, if I just stop in the debug mode at the penultimate line and copy it into the console, then it will plot. Why is that happening? It should behave exactly the same way (I work in Spyder).

Comment: For me, it words both in a script and in the console. (I'm running it on MacOS, Python 3.9.13)

Comment: Try running your script directly on the command line. Perhaps your Spyder set-up is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you, it works now after resetting spyder both in console and in script. But when I add the following two lines at the end, the graph does not update, but the markers disappear only instead of being updated. Why is that?

```
scatter.set_offsets(a1)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue might be related to the way the Spyder IDE handles plotting in interactive mode. When you run a script directly, the plot may not be displayed until the script finishes executing. However, when you run the code line by line in debug mode or execute it in the console afterward, it allows for interactive updates and immediate plotting.

To ensure the plot is displayed even when running the script, you can try adding `

Comment: We can try adding... what?